How does $G_n$ relate to $F_n$ here?
Let $F_n$ be the $n$th Fibonacci number, i.e $$F_n=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}F_{n-1}+F_{n-2} & \text { if } n>1 \\ 1 & \text { if } n=1 \\ 0 & \text { if } n=0\end{array}\right.$$ and define $$G_n = \left\{\begin{array}{cl}G_{n-1}+G_{n-2}+1 & \text { if } n>1 \\ 0 & \text { if } n=1 \\ 0 & \text { if } n=0\end{array}\right.$$ I was trying to reason that $F_n$ and $G_n$ are "about the same" for any $n$; the reason why is that my computer science textbook gives a recursive function to compute $F_n$, and claims without proof that the given function "performs about $F_n$ additions"; $G_n$ is an expression I have written for the number of addition operations used in the function given.
However, I am not really compelled to think that these are similar: because if we define $H_n = G_n-F_n$, for $n>1$, $H_n = H_{n-1} + H_{n-2} + 1$; and it seems that $H_n$ grows exponentially (very much like $F_n$ grows), meaning that $G_n$ grows far faster than $F_n$ does, and is not at all "about the same as $F_n$".
So my question is: what kind of quantitative statement can we make which expresses the similarity between $G_n$ and $F_n$ here? Perhaps we will have to use theta notation (where for functions $f$ and $g$, $f(x) = \Theta(g(x)) \iff \exists a,b \in \mathbb{R} \ a\cdot g(x)\le f(x) \le b \cdot g(x)$), as such notation is used elsewhere in this book.
For additional context, here is the recursive function provided by my textbook:
function fib1(n)
if n=0: return 0
if n=1: return 1
return fib1(n-1) + fib1(n-2)


Similar to the approach in How to solve the difference equation $u_n = u_{n-1} + u_{n-2}+1$ (but with different starting conditions at $n\le 1$), all three sequences grow like $\Theta\left(\varphi^n\right)$.

For an unrelated example: $a(n) = 9n$ and $b(n) = 10n$, their difference $d(n) = b(n) - a(n) = n$ also grows linearly, yet all are $\Theta(n)$. For $a(n)$ and $b(n)$, their "multipliers" by $n$ can be different.

Another quick observation here is that, if you add $1$ to both sides of your recurrence for $G_n$, it becomes $G_n+1=(G_{n-1}+1)+(G_{n-2}+1)$ if $n>1$. So $G_n+1$ satisfies the same recurrence relation as $F_n$, with initial values $G_1+1=G_0+1=1$. Comparing these initial values with those of $F_n$ then gives $G_{n}=F_{n+1}-1$.
